# using replaceAll() to replace part of the matched pattern

Tags: java, regex

A valid pattern to capture the query value in a url could be

```
\(?|&\)[^=]+=([^&]+)
```

How to replace all the **value** of the query in a url using [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Or using other tricks here?

#### Case - 1

```
Actual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=5
Expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=XX
```

#### Case - 2

```
Actual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=5&b=7
Expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=xx&b=xx
```

#### Case - 3

```
Actual: *266 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/user-accounts/malphas/check" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.254.3.0, server: ji, request: "GET /user-accounts/malphas/check?sid=ExecAuthoritySetting HTTP/2.0", host: "jilcom", referrer: "https://jicom/user-accounts/authority/authoritysettings/authoritysetting/detail?sid=ExecAuthoritySetting&roleId=1812""
tid"
Expected: *266 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/user-accounts/malphas/check" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.254.3.0, server: ji, request: "GET /user-accounts/malphas/check?sid=xx HTTP/2.0", host: "jilcom", referrer: "https://jicom/user-accounts/authority/authoritysettings/authoritysetting/detail?sid=xx&roleId=xx""
tid"
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: please provide example use case as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to just match the values of params, you can use this regex using look arounds to match just the values and replace them with `xx` or anything you want.

```
(?<=[&=])[^=&"\n ]*(?=[&" ]|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RbOIfM/5)**

Check out this Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=5",
            "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=5&b=7", "*266 open() \"/usr/local/nginx/html/user-accounts/malphas/check\" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.254.3.0, server: ji, request: \"GET /user-accounts/malphas/check?sid=ExecAuthoritySetting HTTP/2.0\", host: \"jilcom\", referrer: \"https://jicom/user-accounts/authority/authoritysettings/authoritysetting/detail?sid=ExecAuthoritySetting&roleId=1812\"\"tid\"");
    list.forEach(x -> {
        System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.replaceAll("(?<=[&=])[^=&\"\\n ]*(?=[&\" ]|$)", "xx"));
    });
```

Prints,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=5 --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=xx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=5&b=7 --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937940?a=xx&b=xx
*266 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/user-accounts/malphas/check" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.254.3.0, server: ji, request: "GET /user-accounts/malphas/check?sid=ExecAuthoritySetting HTTP/2.0", host: "jilcom", referrer: "https://jicom/user-accounts/authority/authoritysettings/authoritysetting/detail?sid=ExecAuthoritySetting&roleId=1812""tid" --> *266 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/user-accounts/malphas/check" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.254.3.0, server: ji, request: "GET /user-accounts/malphas/check?sid=xx HTTP/2.0", host: "jilcom", referrer: "https://jicom/user-accounts/authority/authoritysettings/authoritysetting/detail?sid=xx&roleId=xx""tid"
```